# Webpack Failed to Compile Simple Application

Tags: webpack

I am new to node and webpack.  I am trying to setup a simple application. I am unable to get webpack to successfully compile the application.  I have been struggling with this for several days.  My application is located at https://github.com/Weste15/test-app.git.  I am getting a long list of errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
webpack built 7244fa5788b2202d1b0e in 46644ms
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 7244fa5788b2202d1b0e
Version: webpack 4.0.1
Time: 46644ms
Built at: 2018-3-2 14:36:59
    Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
bundle.js  11 MiB       0  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
   [1] ./node_modules/path-browserify/index.js 6.04 KiB {0} [built]
  [61] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {0} [built]
 [201] ./node_modules/express/index.js 224 bytes {0} [built]
 [363] (webpack)/lib/webpack.js 6.97 KiB {0} [built]
 [416] ./webpack.config.dev.js 530 bytes {0} [built]
 [417] ./routes/users.js 203 bytes {0} [built]
 [418] ./routes/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
 [420] (webpack)-hot-middleware/middleware.js 3.57 KiB {0} [built]
[1090] ./app.js 843 bytes {0} [built]
[1091] (webpack)-hot-middleware/process-update.js 4.23 KiB {0} [built]
[1096] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js 2.16 KiB {0} [built]
[1098] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
[1099] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js 7.18 KiB {0} [built]
[1100] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.66 KiB {0} [built]
[1101] multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1087 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js
18:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/minify.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
3:2-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
 @ ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/AutomaticPrefetchPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/use/utils.js
3:34-41 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./node_modules/use/utils.js
 @ ./node_modules/use/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/snapdragon/lib/compiler.js
 @ ./node_modules/snapdragon/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/micromatch/lib/utils.js
 @ ./node_modules/micromatch/index.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/optimize/SideEffectsFlagPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js
49:33-53 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/fork.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
79:29-41 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js 7:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in (webpack)/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'inspector' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\debug'
 @ (webpack)/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin.js 8:13-33
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js 3:2-28 7:17-40
 @ (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/AutomaticPrefetchPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.

ERROR in ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/fork.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\worker-farm\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/fork.js 3:21-45
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js
 @ ./node_modules/worker-farm/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/cacache/get.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\cacache'
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/get.js 5:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\chokidar'
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/chownr/chownr.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\chownr'
 @ ./node_modules/chownr/chownr.js 4:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/fix-owner.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/tmp.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/copy-concurrently/copy.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\copy-concurrently'
 @ ./node_modules/copy-concurrently/copy.js 8:13-26
 @ ./node_modules/move-concurrently/move.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/move-file.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/content/write.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/put.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:17-30
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\etag'
 @ ./node_modules/etag/index.js 22:12-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\express\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js 24:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js 8:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\glob'
 @ ./node_modules/glob/sync.js 4:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\glob'
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js 43:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/verify.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\graceful-fs'
 @ ./node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
 @ ./node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/NodeJsInputFileSystem.js
 @ ./node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/node.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/ResolverFactory.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/Compiler.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\graceful-fs'
 @ ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/NodeJsInputFileSystem.js
 @ ./node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/node.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/ResolverFactory.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/Compiler.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js 5:9-22
 @ (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/AutomaticPrefetchPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/make-dir/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\make-dir'
 @ ./node_modules/make-dir/index.js 2:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/find-cache-dir/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\mime'
 @ ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\mkdirp'
 @ ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/move-concurrently/move.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\move-concurrently'
 @ ./node_modules/move-concurrently/move.js 4:13-26
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/move-file.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/content/write.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/put.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/path-exists/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\path-exists'
 @ ./node_modules/path-exists/index.js 2:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/locate-path/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/find-up/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/pkg-dir/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/find-cache-dir/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\rimraf'
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 6:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/rm.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validateOptions.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\schema-utils\dist'
 @ ./node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validateOptions.js 11:10-23
 @ ./node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/schema-utils/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/BannerPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\send'
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 24:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/snapdragon/lib/source-maps.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\snapdragon\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/snapdragon/lib/source-maps.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/snapdragon/lib/compiler.js
 @ ./node_modules/snapdragon/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/micromatch/lib/utils.js
 @ ./node_modules/micromatch/index.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/optimize/SideEffectsFlagPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\node_modules\uglify-es\tools'
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/node_modules/uglify-es/tools/node.js 1:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/minify.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in (webpack)/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\debug'
 @ (webpack)/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin.js 1:11-24
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in (webpack)/lib/node/NodeMainTemplateAsync.runtime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\node'
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeMainTemplateAsync.runtime.js 10:2-15 28:3-16
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeMainTemplatePlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in (webpack)/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\node'
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem.js 7:11-24
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/y18n/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\y18n'
 @ ./node_modules/y18n/index.js 1:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/y.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/locales/en.js
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib'
 @ (webpack)/lib/NormalModule.js 8:21-38
 @ (webpack)/lib/AutomaticPrefetchPlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\node'
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTargetPlugin.js 10:1-18
 @ (webpack)/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\pol2403\Documents\Node\test-app\node_modules\express\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./app.js
 @ multi webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-hot-middleware/client ./app.js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**webpack.config.dev file**

```js
var path = require('path');
webpack = require ('webpack');

module.exports  =  {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js')
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: '/',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/views/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.js$/, 
          exclude: /node_modules/, 
          loaders: ['babel-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.ejs$/,
        loader: 'ejs-loader'} 
    ]
  }
};
```

**app.js**

```js
var path = require ('path');
var express = require ('express');
var webpack = require ('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require ('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware = require ('webpack-hot-middleware');

// routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

config = require ('./webpack.config.dev');

app = express();

// setup view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set ('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use("/", index);
app.use("/users", users);

router = express.Router();

compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {colors: true}
}))

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
    log: console.log
}))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log ('listening on 3000'));

module.exports = app;
```

**views/index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;​
```

**routes/index.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' /> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the error logs more carefully, it's complaining about bunch of things that are missing. If you google them you will probably find your answers.

I think you are most likely using Webpack v5 which dropped bunch of polyfills that would normally be included, like `fs` and `process`. [Read more about it here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) and especially [how they removed NodeJS polyfills](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/) in their release notes

> webpack 5 stops automatically polyfilling these core modules and focus on frontend-compatible modules. Our goal is to improve compatibility with the web platform, where Node.js core modules are not available.

This is just my hunch, reading it from this error message in stack trace you provided:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Your webpack configuration is aimed at web (via `target`) property so `fs` module for manipulating file system is obviously not available in browsers. But I see your application is using **express** which runs in NodeJS environemnts. So I think you should switch your `target` to `node` and read about Webpack NodeJS configuration. There are [articles](https://medium.com/@binyamin/creating-a-node-express-webpack-app-with-dev-and-prod-builds-a4962ce51334) that will help you.